# Why is my code failing? Trying to replace arrow expression with basic one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.:

```
var questions = qnumbers.map((i, el) => ({
            number: el.innerHTML,
            text: qtext[i].innerHTML,
            feedback: qfeedback[i].innerHTML,
            lessonid: strLESSONID.toString(),
            sessionid: strSESSIONID.toString(),
            userid: strUSERID.toString(),
            correctanswer: qcorrectanswer[i].innerHTML,
            studentanswer: qstudentanswer[i].innerHTML
        })).get();
```

Only thing it doesn't work on is IE -_- and I KNOW it is because of the '=>' but I am attempting to rewrite the code to not include it but it doesn't seem to be working? **That is the part I need help with, NOT why it is happening... So don't close my question again please.**

Here is the code that I have tried to change it to, but to no avail, I have JQUERY too so we can use that if necessary.

```
var questions = qnumbers.map(function(i, el){
            number: el.innerHTML,
            text: qtext[i].innerHTML,
            feedback: qfeedback[i].innerHTML,
            lessonid: strLESSONID.toString(),
            sessionid: strSESSIONID.toString(),
            userid: strUSERID.toString(),
            correctanswer: qcorrectanswer[i].innerHTML,
            studentanswer: qstudentanswer[i].innerHTML      
        }).get();
```

I get syntax error: 'expecting ; on line text: qtext[i].innerHTML'

Thank you!

Comment: In a plain `function` you'll need a `return` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return an object:

```
var questions = qnumbers.map(function(i, el){
        return {
          number: el.innerHTML,
          text: qtext[i].innerHTML,
          feedback: qfeedback[i].innerHTML,
          lessonid: strLESSONID.toString(),
          sessionid: strSESSIONID.toString(),
          userid: strUSERID.toString(),
          correctanswer: qcorrectanswer[i].innerHTML,
          studentanswer: qstudentanswer[i].innerHTML
        }      
    }).get();
```

when you write `function() {}`, the brackets, `{}`, do not represent the start and end of an object, they represent the start and end of the function. Normal javascript functions have no concept of an implicitly returned value - you have to return something. Only arrow functions can have that implicitly returned value syntax, `() => obj`